# Android - Location Permission - reponse from alert box

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

[image]

Hello guys,

I'm developing an app using react native.

How can I know the value pressed for this alert box on Android ?

I would actually need to immediately listen to the response from that alert box to display a component on the screen in the background.  If access is denied, I will show component X else component Y.

Thanks and Kind Regards,
Avinash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.setState({
      hasPermission:false
   })
}
requestMultiplePermission =  async () => {
const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      {
        title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
        message:
          'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
          'so you can take awesome pictures.',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('You can use the camera');
      this.setState({hasPermission:true})
    } else {
      console.log('Camera permission denied');
    }

}

componentDidMound() => {
   if(Platform.OS == "android"){
   this.requestMultiplePermission()
   }
}

render() {

  return(
     ...
     {this.state.hasPermission && <View><Text>has permission</Text></View>}
     {!this.state.hasPermission && <View><Text>not have permission</Text> 
     </View>}

     ...

   )

}
```

the return graned is the result for wether permission gets.
every time you use permission, you should check it firstly.

Comment: I updated the question : I would actually need to immediately listen to the response from that alert box to display a component on the screen in the background.  If access is denied, I will show component X else component Y.

Comment: this is need time to return because it needs user select. when the user selects, it returns immediately, then you can change my console.log with setState to update

Comment: @Avinash Lingaloo, for a new problem, you should ask a new question, not update it. otherwise, make the answer useless